# Converting from Python 2 to Python 3: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I was given the following Python 2x code. I went to convert it to Python 3x by changing `import urllib2` to `from urllib.request import urlopen`. I got rid of the urllib2 reference and ran the program. The document at the end of the url was retrieved, but the program failed at the line indicated, throwing the error

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

The document looks like this: `b'9306112 9210128 9202065 \r\n9306114 9204065 9301122 \r\n9306115 \r\n9306116 \r\n9306117 \r\n9306118 \r\n9306119`

I tried playing with the return value at that line and the one above (e.g., converting to bytes, splitting on different values), but nothing worked. Any thoughts as to what is happening?

```
import urllib2


CITATION_URL = "http://storage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-alg/alg_phys-cite.txt"

def load_graph(graph_url):
    """
    Function that loads a graph given the URL
    for a text representation of the graph

    Returns a dictionary that models a graph
    """
    graph_file = urllib2.urlopen(graph_url)
    graph_text = graph_file.read()
    graph_lines = graph_text.split('\n') <--- The Problem
    graph_lines = graph_lines[ : -1]

    print "Loaded graph with", len(graph_lines), "nodes"

    answer_graph = {}
    for line in graph_lines:
        neighbors = line.split(' ')
        node = int(neighbors[0])
        answer_graph[node] = set([])
        for neighbor in neighbors[1 : -1]:
            answer_graph[node].add(int(neighbor))

    return answer_graph

citation_graph = load_graph(CITATION_URL)
print(citation_graph)
```

Comment: In python3 you will have to decode when reading bytes. graph_text.decode("utf-8") to perform string operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to treat a `bytes` object like a string, you need to decode it first. For example:

```
graph_text = graph_file.read().decode("utf-8")
```

if the encoding is UTF-8. This should allow you to treat this as a string instead of a sequence of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You can only split likes with likes - if you want to split with `\n` while still keeping `graph_text` as `bytes`, define the split as a `bytes` sequence, too:

```
graph_lines = graph_text.split(b'\n')
```

Otherwise, if you know the codec your `graph_text` data was encoded with, first decode it into a `str` with: `graph_text.decode("<codec>")` and then continue treating it as a `str`.